# Widgets not showing up when i come back to the Widget page Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I am using WordPress version 4.3.1.

I im using twentyfifteen  theam that came with wordpress. I have added the following code to the **page.php**

```
<!-- This is image 1-->
<?php echo '<div class="kbodymain"> <br>'; ?>
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Image One')) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "<marquee>";
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category=1&orderby=post_title&order=ASC');
foreach($posts as $post)
the_title("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ");
echo "</marquee>";
    echo '</div><br><br>';
?>
<!-- End Of Image 1 -->



<!-- This is image 2-->
<?php echo '<div class="kbodymain"> <br>'; ?>
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Image Two')) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "<marquee>";
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category=2&orderby=post_title&order=ASC');
foreach($posts as $post)
the_title("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ");
echo "</marquee>";
    echo '</div><br><br>';
?>
<!-- End Of Image 2 -->






<!-- This is image 3-->
<?php echo '<div class="kbodymain"> <br>'; ?>
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Image Three')) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "<marquee>";
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category=3&orderby=post_title&order=ASC');
foreach($posts as $post)
the_title("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ");
echo "</marquee>";
    echo '</div><br><br>';
?>
<!-- End Of Image 3 -->





<!-- This is image 4-->
<?php echo '<div class="kbodymain"> <br>'; ?>
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Image Four')) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "<marquee>";
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category=4&orderby=post_title&order=ASC');
foreach($posts as $post)
the_title("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ");
echo "</marquee>";
    echo '</div><br><br>';
?>
<!-- End Of Image 4 -->




<!-- This is image 5-->
<?php echo '<div class="kbodymain"> <br>'; ?>
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('Image Five')) : ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "<marquee>";
$posts = get_posts('numberposts=10&category=5&orderby=post_title&order=ASC');
foreach($posts as $post)
the_title("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; ");
echo "</marquee>";
    echo '</div><br><br>';
?>
<!-- End Of Image 5 -->
```

I have also added the following code to **funcations.php**

```
function twentyfifteen_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Widget Area', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'twentyfifteen' ),
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ) );


register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Image One',
        'id' => 'Image_One',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));


register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Image Two',
        'id' => 'Image_Two',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));



register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Image Three',
        'id' => 'Image_Three',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));

register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Image Four',
        'id' => 'Image_Four',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));

register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Image Five',
        'id' => 'Image_Five',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));

register_sidebar(array(
        'name'=> 'Image Six',
        'id' => 'Image_Six',
        'before_widget' => '',
        'after_widget' => '',
        'before_title' => '',
        'after_title' => '',
    ));



}
```

When i go to appearances > Widgets > then drag image widget to any of the Image# then select an image save and then refresh the page the image widget goes missing but some times it shows back up on the website even if it does not show up in the image# box.

Here is a link to the plugin im using. https://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/

**Note: that this does it with any available widget including text!**

Did i code something wrong?

Thank you for your help!